# Python- Convert multiple list into multiple dataframes

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a project to get any csv file in one specifc location and convert each csv into one dataframe.

As you can see, it was not necessary to put the names of the files, it simply takes every file it finds and converts it into a list, but now I want to convert those lists into daframes, the name of the dataframes can be generic. Any way to do this?  how to get out of the list these dataframes?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
  
# assign path
path, dirs, files = next(os.walk("/Users/user/Documents/appfolio"))
file_count = len(files)
# create empty list
dataframes_list = []
  
# append datasets to the list 
for i in range(file_count):
    temp_df = pd.read_csv("/Users/user/Documents/appfolio/"+files[i] , encoding='windows-1252')
    dataframes_list.append(temp_df)
      
for dataset in dataframes_list:
    display(dataset)
```

[image]

Comment: forget it - keep it as list. even If you assign every dataframe to unique variale then you will have only problem to work with this. And when you keep on list then you can use `for`-loop to execute command on all dataframes.

Comment: if you need unique names then keep in dictionary and use filename as key

Comment: You lose no functionality of data frames if stored in list or dict. Simply reference by number (or name for dicts) accordingly: `mylist[1].head()`, `mylist[2].tail()`, `mylist[3].describe()`...